# Why not working when I click on the links in the top menu?

Tags: html, css

I have this page:

[NSFW link](http://www.altradona.ro/)

On this page I have some links section above `CONTUL MEU | FAVORITE |CHECKOUT | LOGIN | SIGN UP`

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="grid_12">
    <h1 class="logo">//some code HTML</h1>
    <div class="nav-container">
        //some code HTML
    </div>
    <div class="top-dropdowns">
        //some code HTML
     </div>
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.grid_12 {
    width: 1170px;
    z-index: 100;  //If I delete the code then runs
    margin-top: -28px; //If I delete the code then runs}
```

How can I make my DVD pass underneath to keep the design and to give and click on the buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `z-index:99999` to `.top-switch-bg` class.

[z-index documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

```
.top-switch-bg {
    z-index: 99999; //added this
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,work but my logo is hidden if i add this code...you tried to add this code to see?:D

Comment: Just remove `margin-top: -28px;` to `.grid_12` and bug is fixed

Comment: yes but spoil logo position ... he must remain where it is ... should the logo be above\